# Quarkus: how to print properties from the interface with @ConfigMapping

Tags: java, quarkus

I am studying quarkus now. As I understand it, the properties from `application.properties` can be obtained using `@ConfigMapping`. But I need to print the properties that turned out. Previously, I would have done this by overriding `toString()` in the class, but here is the interface.

```
@ConfigMapping(prefix = "server")
interface Server {
    String host();

    int port();
}
```

I tried to replace the interface with a class, but I got an error: @ConfigMapping annotation can only be placed in interface

How do I output properties to the log?

Comment: Why do you need a `toString` method? If you reallly do, you can add a `default` method to the interface

Answer (score 0):

Welcome aboard Inessa,

Let's assume you have the following properties in your application.properties:

```
server.host=localhost
server.port=8080
```

Then your class:

```
@ConfigMapping(prefix = "server")
interface Server {
    @WithName("host")
    String host();
    @WithName("port")
    int port();
}
```

In your code:

```
Server.host();
Server.port();
```